# Split one Name Column into Two Columns using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working with SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 with Excel 2007.

I am building a package that will pull information from a `.CSV` file and import it into a table in a DB that we are creating for an HRIS project.

The `.CSV` file has the following fields starting in B9 and running through column J (row length will vary)

```
| PersNo | IDNo | Name | PArea | OrgUnit | OrgName | UserID | EntryDate |
```

The issue I have is that I need to take the `Name` column and split it into a `FirstName` and `LastName` columns. I have scoured the internet and found a number of forums that detail methods that use Derived Columns, Conditional Split, Script Component and MultiCast. None of them were helpful or fit my needs.

The issue is complicated by the name arrangement. I have three different name types that can be displayed.

```
John Smith
John A Smith
John Smith III
```

The last two they will need to be split differently.

If there is a middle initial they want it split as such.

```
| FirstName | LastName |
------------------------
| John      | Smith A  |
```

i.e. Smith and the Middle Initial will be in the `LastName` column

If they have a suffix then they will need to be split as such.

```
| FirstName | LastName  |
-------------------------
| John      | Smith III |
```

i.e. Smith and the suffix will be in the `LastName` column

I need to know if there is a way that I can split this out in one package.

Eventually this will be automated to run daily so I will also have to utilize a lookup I assume to filter out any duplicates and enter only new data.

I appreciate anything information that anyone can provide.

Comment: So what if you have `John A Smith III`?

Comment: I didn't think about that one but that is a possibility that I didn't consider. In that case the A and the III would both be at the end with the suffix being the last bit. |John | Smith A III|.

Comment: Derived Columns or Script Task would work -- both approaches are outlined 
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2eb394d0-2cd8-4402-9bb4-14a03ccc4460/split-flat-file-column-data-into-multiple-columns-using-ssis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parseing names is surprisingly difficult due to the numerous variations even in just a single culture, as you have already identified. If you can go back to the source data from where the CSV generated and extract this information then that would be preferable but...

One way to handle this is to use several Regular Expressions in a Script Component. Each regex would be responsible for picking out a part of the name which you will later be able to concatenate as you like.

Try something like this, you may have to tweak the regex's, they're definately not my strongest point, and as time goes on you may find cases that don't fit, but it gives you a start.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    const string pFirstName = @"^[A-Z]([-']?[a-z]+)*";
    const string pSuffix = @"((Jr|Sr|I|V|X)( ?))*";
    const string pInitial = @"(?<=\s)[A-Z](?=\s)";
    const string pLastName = @"(?!(?:Jr|Sr|I|V|X|^))([A-Z][-'\s]?[a-z]+)";

    string fullName = Row.Name.ToString();
    string firstName = Regex.Match(fullName, pFirstName).Value;
    string suffix = Regex.Match(fullName, pSuffix).Value;
    string initial = Regex.Match(fullName, pInitial).Value;
    string lastName = Regex.Match(fullName, pLastName).Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initial))
        lastName += " " + initial;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix))
        lastName += " " + suffix;

    Row.FirstName = firstName;
    Row.LastName = lastName;
}
```

Edit: I have made a simple project demoing the above and showing all three forms of the script component, you can download it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/parsename)

Comment: TI, thank you for the response. I am new to the Script component so please forgive me for the follow up question.

Comment: TI, Thank you for the info. I have never used the script component, where would I enter this information. Looking at it i would assume the "Edit Script" button and then replace the base.PreExecute(); with the script above. Then delete everything else. If I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: OK, figured out some of what i was doing wrong by looking at the link provided by Mr.Reband I went to the output and added the FirstName and LastName to it. Now all of the red squiggles are gone with the exception of one. The "void" on the public override void. Any idea why?

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker one of the keys to the script component is to have your connection and input/output columns sorted before trying to edit the script, [here](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=ssis+script+component&view=detail&mid=73CE88B10C7C8B12C62C73CE88B10C7C8B12C62C&first=0&FORM=NVPFVR) looks to be quite a good video, hope this helps. If you hover the mouse over the squiggle it will give you more info, I suspect you may not be using it as a transformation component...

Comment: Thank you for the video, that will come in very handy for another project i will be working on later. I did do the script component as a transformation, when I hovered over the "void" it said the following. "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct.

Comment: just to give an overview of what i have done, I set the input column as Name from the .CSV file. I added an lastname and firstname output column. I removed all of the confusing info from the edit script page and added just your script. then I added the flatfile connection to the connection manager.

Comment: I also have a red x on the component, when I mouse over the x it says "The binary code for the script is not found" then tells me to edit it in the script editor.

Comment: at Execution: TITLE: Package Validation Error Package Validation Error Error at NewHire_Task [Script Component [45]]: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
Error at NewHire_Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error at NewHire_Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation. Error at NewHire_Task: There were errors during task validation. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker sorry it should be `Row.FirstName` not `output0buffer` have amended this

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker Glad your close to getting it working but you should avoid conversing in the comments - don't mean to sound unfriendly it's just the way it is on SO. Thanks